# Reusing Controls in WCF

Tags: wcf, controls

I use WCF for different functions / data that I use in outlook add-in, websites, adobe add-in, etc. 
I want to have a few different controls (something like a user control) saved within this WCF, and then I will call this control within my projects. This will save me from recoding / updating all these controls in all my different project.

Is this possible in WCF?

Comment: It can be done but I do not think it services should be used to create and send controls.

Comment: What you really mean by "Reusing Controls in WCF"? Even title doesn't make sense.

Comment: Don't you mean "WPF", not "WCF"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF service (implementation) code is just **regular, normal .NET** server-side code (of course: no UI) - nothing "magic" or special about it at all.

So yes, **of course** you can reuse code!

Just put that code for your "controls" (rather: components) into a common assembly and use that assembly from multiple WCF service implementation classes - and you're all set!

**Update:** based on your comment - WCF is a **web service** and XML messaging system - it's designed to get requests, process them, and return **data**.

But WCF is **definitely NOT** suited to return UI controls from it's calls! That's a totally wrong approach. Don't use WCF as a "UI builder" - that's not what it's job is!

Comment: Basically what you're saying is to create the controls with just server-side code and then use it?

Comment: @marc_s If you weren't sure about question, then what your answer is?

Comment: @marc_s I agree with you! Trying to help is good thing! But I don't think so this question is fulfilling http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx (Your rules) these tips.

Comment: I had wanted to really create a UI and then reuse it in the different projects.

Comment: @user3354572: but WCF is really not the tool to "create an UI" - WCF is a **data-based web service** - it can return data from database or other sources - it is definitely **NOT** designed to return UI controls!

Comment: For example, I have a group of controls (3 dropdownlists populated from the database, checkboxes, textboxes populated based on different text entered, etc.). I need to incorporate these controls within adobe addin, outlook add-in, a few web pages. I wanted to be able to create this group of controls with all the functionality in one place and then call it from the different projects.  Based on your answer, it seems like wcf is not the place for this. Is this possible?

Comment: @user3354572: WCF is the mechanism to **get the data** for these controls to display; but WCF is not the tool to actually **return** those controls (as objects) per se

Comment: What would be the place for this then? Or do I need to create this in each addin / project individually?

Comment: @user3354572: just create a regular class library with custom controls and use that library in various projects. Use WCF to supply the data to display in those controls! :-)

Comment: thanks. Any project that doesn't use .net though (adobe add-in), can use the wcf for the data, but would need to have its own controls created there, I assume.